# Modifying the "active" css for bootstrap's typeahead

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap had a bug in 2.2.1 with inheritance for typeahead - that has been fixed in 2.2.2.

Comment: as a grammatical note, your right nav has a link for "Editors' Thoughts" (i.e. - plural possessive), though the full section is "Editor's Note" (i.e. - singular possessive)

Comment: not to nitpick, but if you're going to have thoughts from multiple editors then you'd want it to be "Editors' Thoughts"; however, if the only thoughts are going to be from one editor (i.e. - kurtis), then it should be "Editor's Thoughts". again, not trying to be a grammar goon (and sorry if it's coming out that way), just passing it on.

Comment: There are multiple editors. So instead of being concise, I just went for the general case.

I do appreciate what you are saying.

Answer (score 4):

The Bootstrap Typeahead dropdown dynamically generates the following HTML:

```
  <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">
      ...
      <li><a href="#">MATCHING RESULT</a></li>
      ...
  </ul>
```

The default CSS rule that applies is also the one styling drop down menus.

```
.dropdown-menu .active > a,
.dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #0081c2;
    ...
}
```

So to override the typeahead without changing the drop down menu, you'll need to add a rule somewhere after this one. I place mine in a separate file after I load the bootstrap.css.*

```
.typeahead .active > a,
.typeahead .active > a:hover {
    color: white;

    /* Change the typeahead background color here if you'd like */
    background-color: Green;

    /* Turns off the default background gradients */
    background-image: none;
}
```

**Best practice recommends that you combine and minimize all CSS when you go to production, but regardless, this rule should be after the one above unless you make it more specific than the .dropdown-menu rule*

Answer (score 0):

It is the line 2838 in the bootstrap.css file just change it to:

```
color: white;
```

If you are working with the .less files your going to have to do some digging around in the dropdown.less file I believe.  If that happens just do a quick search for: ".dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a {" and you can find it that way.

Comment: That's the dropdown. I'm talking about typeahead in the search box

Comment: Right but the typeahead ul that you're talking about also has the class "dropdown-menu" so I still have to reiterate the above answer.

Comment: I see. This makes no sense then. The dropdown has the text-color as white, but the typeahead has black.

Comment: Actually right now it is the ".dropdown-menu .active > a" selector that is making the font color black.  While .dropdown-menu may have the color set to white, all child links in active class are being set to black.  Trust me.  Just look in the dropdown.less file for that selector.