# Angular Bootstrap Typeahead look

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

I need to to customise the look of typeahead results. What are the css selectors to choose container and items? I could not find any information in Angular UI documentation and Bootstrap documentation as well.

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13749101/1477118), that Bootstrap automatically generates the following html:

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">
    ...
    <li><a href="#">MATCHING RESULT</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

However, specifying class .typeahead in CSS did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: @DavidG It is Angular UI Bootstrap

Comment: I mean for the typeahead library?

Comment: For info, I ask because Bootstrap doesn't come with a typeahead library any more. The question you linked refers to Bootstrap 2 which you are not using.

Comment: @DavidG I use Typeahead (ui.bootstrap.typeahead) directive from Angular UI Bootstrap library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Angular UI demo page](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), the HTML output appears to be (trimmed a lot of stuff that didn't appear to be useful):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope" role="listbox" typeahead-popup="" matches="matches">
    <li class="ng-scope">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Element 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ng-scope active">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Element 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ng-scope">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Element 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So you can change the look of all `.dropdown-menu` items, or it may be preferable to wrap your typeahead in it's own `div`.

```
<div class="custom-typeahead">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

With CSS like these.

The entire dropdown:

```
.custom-typeahead .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Individual items in dropdown:

```
.custom-typeahead .dropdown-menu li {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Actively selected item in dropdown:

```
.custom-typeahead .dropdown-menu li.active {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: DavidG - What if I have the dropdown-menu appended to body and have several instances of it triggered from different elements with different styling. I dont want to directly style like body > .dropdown-menu. Is there a way I can add my custom class to the dropdown?